# ADC unable to read from multiple channels

Tags: avr, adc, c, atmega

The problem is that I am unable to read from multiple ADC channels (atmega8-au). The code works fine if only one channel is used eg. `ADC0`, however, if the second channel `ADC1` is used then the value of `readADC1` is equal to `readADC0`.

What should I do this to fix the problem? Might it be related to resetting the `ADMUX` bits?

The related code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

unsigned int threshold = 900;
volatile unsigned int sensor_left = 0;
volatile unsigned int sensor_center = 0;
volatile unsigned int sensor_right = 0;

void init()
{
    DDRD |= 1 << PORTD0;
    DDRD |= 1 << PORTD1;

    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (0 << ADPS1) | (0 << ADPS0); //1MHz / 16 = 62.5kHz
}

unsigned int readADC0()
{
    ADMUX |= (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0);
    ADMUX |= (0 << ADLAR);
    ADMUX |= (0 << MUX3) | (0 << MUX2) | (0 << MUX1) | (0 << MUX0);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));
    return ADC;
}

unsigned int readADC1()
{
    ADMUX |= (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0);
    ADMUX |= (0 << ADLAR);
    ADMUX |= (0 << MUX3) | (0 << MUX2) | (0 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX0);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));
    return ADC;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    init();

    while (1) {    
        sensor_left = readADC1();
        sensor_center = readADC0(); //false results if enabled

        if (sensor_left < threshold) {
            PORTD |= 1 << PORTD0;
        } else {
            PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD0);
        }

        if (sensor_center < threshold) {
            PORTD |= 1 << PORTD1;
        } else {
            PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And we are just supposed to guess what hardware is involved?

Comment: Updated, it's `atmega8-au` @PlasmaHH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the way you set the value of ADMUX. By using |= you are not able to set the value of a bit to 0, only to 1. So when you want to set the value of the bit MUX0 to 0 it is still 1 from the previous assignment (1 | 0 == 1). Try setting each bit to the desired value (for this you cat find tons of tutorials online about bitwise operations: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bit-manipulation-aka-programming-101?page=all ).

Comment: Ahh, my bad. That logical or got me :D thank you for the correction.